# How to apply manually obtained mesh leveling values to a G-code file on a printer without ABL?

Tags: bed-leveling, pronterface

I have a Raise3D Pro2, which if you are not aware, is one of the most overbuilt, overpriced printers that lacks some of the most basic features of an Ender costing 1/10<sup>th</sup> the price. One of which is ABL.

I wish to generate a mesh with a dial indicator temporarily attached to the carriage, and then apply that mesh to a G-code file.

How would one do such a thing once they have manually recoded the offset values for their grid?

Comment: Hello Benram, I've updated the question to temper the frustration ;-), I imagine you are not happy with the printer, for such a price I would have selected the Ultimaker instead. I hope you know what firmware the firmware of this printer is based on?

Comment: That was intentional. I wanted anyone who reads this to understand why they should never buy one of these!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the firmware, e.g. Marlin firmware can set a mesh through G-codes when the firmware is set to Unified Bed Levelling (UBL).

However, Raise3D is using a closed source of which is unknown on which the firmware is based. You can most probably not use the Marlin firmware commands.

If you want to adjust for a measured build plate surface geometry, you can always fall back on developing a software program to alter your created G-code source file.

If you map the surface you can describe the height as function of X, Y coordinates. The current height value should be compensated for that mesh. A relative simple program (or plugin, e.g. Python script) should be able to alter the first 10 mm of G-codes where you smooth out the mesh to zero compensation at 10 mm height. Basically this is what the Marlin firmware does, compensation for the surface geometry.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. A great idea, but I was hoping someone else had already coded such a script. Given how much hate there is for this model's shortcomings from other users, it would be the logical course of action. While it is technically simple and within my coding skills, I do not have the time to tackle such an endeavour at this time unfortunately. I will likely not keep the printer.